# Permissions at azure blob level

Tags: azure

Is it possible to set permissions on a blob per blob basis in Windows Azure?

I'm trying to set some of the blobs as public and some private based on a user being anonymous or being logged in to my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the permissions are set on a container. However, nothing is preventing you from using 1 container per blob (you can have a huge nomber of containers)